# Any $X\in O^+(n)$ (orthogonal matrices with positive determinant) is the product of an even number of reflections?

Tags: matrices

> Any $X\in O^+(n)$ (orthogonal matrices with positive determinant) is the product of an even number of reflection?

I am not able to prove this. Please help.

Comment: What do you know about $O(n)$ ?

Comment: $O(n)$ is compact. determinants are $\{+1,-1\}$, collumn vectors are orthonormal.

Comment: See here http://math.stackexchange.com/q/138020/30357 for an answer without the positivity assumption. To finish an answer to your question, you only need to know how reflections influence the determinant.

Comment: Hint: what is the determinant of (a matrix representing) a reflection?

Answer (score 5):

I'm imagining you may be interested in the case $K = \mathbb{R}$, $q = x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2$, but the result holds more generally:

Theorem (Cartan-Dieudonne): Let $q = q(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be a nondegenerate quadratic form over a field $K$ of characteristic different from $2$.  Then every element of the orthogonal group $O(q)$ of $q$ is a product of at most $n$ reflections.

For a proof see e.g. $\S 8.4$ in [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/quadraticforms.pdf).

Since the determinant of a reflection is $-1$, an element of $O(q)$ has determinant $+1/-1$ according to whether it can be written as a product of an even/odd number of reflections.

Answer (score 3):

Since the OP asked this as a follow up to one of my [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100978/how-many-connected-components-does-mathrmgl-n-mathbb-r-have/100985#100985), I guess I should answer this one.

You need to know some basic facts about orthogonal matrices:

- that $X\in O(n)$ if and only if the columns of $X$ form an orthonormal system which is again equivalent to the fact that the rows of $X$ are an orthonormal base.
- that for any two unit vectors $v, w$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ there exists a reflection $R$ such that $Rv=w$.
- the product of orthogonal matrices is orthogonal.
- the inverse of an orthogonal matrix is it's transpose.

If you know that then you will easily see that, if $X =(r_1, \ldots, r_n)$ with an orthonormal base $\{r_i\}$, there exists a reflection $R_1$ such that $R_1 X=(e_1, r_2', \cdots , r_n')$, where $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$. $R_1 X$ is again orthogonal (third statement above). So the first row of this matrix is $(1,0, ,\ldots,0)$, that is, $R_1X$ is an orthogonal matrix with a $1$ in the upper left corner and zeroes in the other entries of the first row and column. Now a simple induction shows that there exist (at most) $n$ reflections which transform $X$ into the identity matrix, i.e.
$$R_n\cdots R_1 X = Id $$

Since the inverse of an orthogonal matrix is simply the transpose you get
$$X = (R_n\cdots R_1)^T  $$

The four basic propeties I mentionend should be easy to find in any basic text book.

(The fact that the number of reflections is even follows by taking determinants).

Comment: could you tell me how to prove the basic fact number two? which fact you used to write $R_1X=(e_1,r_2',\dots,r_n')$?

Comment: @Patience the idea is to use the reflection through the hyperplane which bisects the angle between $v$ and $w$. That is, the reflection through the plane normal to $N=v-w$, which is given explicitly by $$r\mapsto r-2\langle r, \frac{N}{|N|}\rangle\frac{ N}{|N|}$$  (If f$w=v$ take any hyperplane $E$ containing them and reflect through $E$).

Comment: what is $r$? ??

Comment: @Patience $r$ is the free variable, a vector in Euclidean space. The reflection is given by $$Rr = r-2\langle r, n\rangle n$$ with $n=N/|N|$.